# LDAP The server is not operational

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have this LDAP problem where the server is not operational.

Here's my code

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry();
directoryEntry.Path = "LDAP://";
directoryEntry.Username = myusername;
directoryEntry.Password = mypass;

DirectorySearcher objDirSearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
SearchResult objSearchResult;

if (objDirSearch != null)
{
    objDirSearch.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", "abcd");

    MessageBox.Show(directoryEntry.Username);

    objSearchResult = objDirSearch.FindOne();
}
```

Please help me I'm stuck and frustrated

Comment: Don't create a new exception. It's pointless. Just let the old one be thrown, with its original message, stack trace, etc. Fix that and post the resulting stack trace.

Comment: here's my error message
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
   at MVExtension.MVExtensionObject.CheckUniquenessInAD(String attributeName, String searchCriteria)

Comment: at MVExtension.MVExtensionObject.GetUniqueCn(MVEntry mventry)
   at MVExtension.MVExtensionObject.ProvisionAD(MVEntry mventry)
   at MVExtension.MVExtensionObject.Provision(MVEntry mventry)

Comment: `LDAP://` on its own is not a valid LDAP path .....

Comment: i use only ip address for LDAP://

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "abcd");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!